# I am getting error while using login API https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=<YOUR APP APP KEY>&pretty_json=true

Tags: appcelerator

While doing a login using `https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=<YOUR APP APP KEY>&pretty_json=true` REST endpoint we are getting error:

> Error : No connection could be made because target machine actively refused it

We are doing this call using C# from a remote server.

Comment: Could it be that you are behind some sort of firewall that blocks our server? Can you try from another internet connection? If that still fails, then please report it as bug at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). Link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Thanks Fokke for providing this information really appreciate.